# which of the three fluent expressions below best matches the user story?

Tags: c#, coding-style, fluent-interface

I am working on a fluent framework, and I was looking to get some feedback from other engineers as to which fluent expression is the most aligned with the user story that I have.

User Story: "as a software engineer using fluent framework X, when the framework's event aggregator publishes an event, I want to map / route this event to a method on my controller and then show a view in a UI container."

Option 1:

```
Map<MyEvent>()
.To<MyView, MyController>(controller => controller.HandleMyEvent());
```

Option 2:

```
Map<MyEvent>()
.To<MyView>()
.Via<MyController>(controller => controller.HandleMyEvent());
```

Option 3:

```
Map<MyEvent>()
.To<MyController>(controller => controller.HandleMyEvent())
.Show<MyView>()
.InContainer<MainTabContainer>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "as a software engineer using fluent
>   framework X, when the framework's
>   event aggregator publishes an event, I
>   want to map / route this event to a
>   method on my controller and then show
>   a view in a UI container."

here is what it sounds like you want your code to say:
***send event X to my controller and show result in a UI container.***
then you feed that into google English-to-c# translator and you get:

```
Route<MyEvent>().To<MyController>(c=>c.HandleMyEvent()).AndShowResultIn<MyUIContainer>();
```

Specifying both view and controller when you setup event routing. View-Controller mapping needs to be specified, but not in the same sentence as setting up event routing. So do it separately:

```
Bind<MyView>().To<MyController>();
```

or bind controller to the view, and then route event to the view, instead of controller, I wouldn't though. Stick with routing events through controller.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion...  I like it "Route<MyEvent>().To<MyController>(c=>c.HandleMyEvent()).AndShowResultIn<MyUIContainer>();"

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to say without the whole context of your system. For example I don't know the role of UI container, why it is defined only in Option 3 and what does it mean for two first options. I'll assume that there is some convention that decides which UI container to use by default.

**Option 1** doesn't look like natural sentence and two generic parameters in a row make it less readable than Option 2 & 3.

**Option 3** contains two sentences, `Show` is the second verb here. I like APIs that have one sentence per chain, but that may be only my personal preference.

**Option 2** is a natural sentence with clear meaning and short, single words, I like it the most for sure. If only there's a way to override the default UI container (using something like i.e. `To<MainTabContainer>().In<MyView>()`), it will be definitely the best.

Comment: it would be very hard to give you the entire context of the system.  There is no way in the current system to specify a target container (that I am aware of), and the current framework shows the view contitionally, based on what the controller's HandleMyEvent returns.  Option 1 & 2 exist, and they hurt my brain.  The "user story" is what I have to do, and I was really curious if Option 3 best describes the user story.